# Why is it that using cell phone can invite lighting strike?

Tags: lightning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to use any wireless device during a lightning storm?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/is-it-safe-to-use-any-wireless-device-during-a-lightning-storm)

We often hear the tale that a person gets stuck by lighting when he is unfortunate enough to use a cell phone outdoor.

But why is this so?

Comment: I am voting to close this. I don't think there is any need for this site to debunk obviously false rumors that some run-off-the-mill journalist happens to publish.

Comment: Next time we will obviously also have to answer "Why is it that Angelina Jolie uses bubble chamber in her bath?", "Why is it that people don't fall into space from the opposite side of the Earth?" and "How many elephants carry the Discworld?" *Well, the last one is actually the only question that makes some sense* :-)

Comment: Also during lightening storms cell phones don't normally work. :)

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer Mine phone works pretty well; but we have a dense network here in Europe and I live in a city.

Comment: @Charmer: actually, *that* would make a pretty good question: "How do clouds/thunderstorms affect propagation of certain EM waves?"

Comment: because your reception in the safe faraday cage of your car was not good enough...